# Unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance transitions for <nameOfProject.secondViewController: 0x135d2a120>

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, animation

I am using the following pod: https://github.com/xxxAIRINxxx/MusicPlayerTransition. 
When I do the music player transition and I close it, the collection view or the table view what I am showing on the actual view controller seams ok but when I try to do a segue on the table to another viewcontroller who has a table said this: `unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance transitions for`. So I think the error is on the pod. So my question is if anybody can check what is the error or how can I prevent this error for showing the table correctly after close the player.

Answer (score 0):

If it were the pod you'd have seen others with the same problem show up when you googled. Show your code especially where you transition to the second controller. I'm sure you'll get help.